# Rails migrating multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, database-migration

A Rails migration may change two columns like this:

```
change_column :users, :screen_name, :string, limit: 255
change_column :users, :full_name,   :string, limit: 255
```

Is there any way to make these happen simultaneously?

Comment: Nope, migration should be step by step, and what of your purpose of doing this?

Comment: Performance. I guess it will probably be faster for the DB to run them at the same time.

Comment: the same with adding 3 fields and 3 indexes to a table with 25M rows. takes half a day - but thats the deal.

Comment: I don't know the details but it's certainly conceivable that there's a performance benefit in some engines, e.g. due to the fixed overhead of iterating and locking rows. MySQL supports it in one command fwiw.

Comment: What difference does it make unless you're trying to change 3000 columns at once?

Comment: No idea. I assume it depends on the nature of the data and the database+engine involved. I'm almost certain there would be little downside to this and potentially big upside. If you have evidence indicating it would have negligible difference in all situations, please share.